# $_SESSION Variable Only Stores Some Values

Tags: php, html, session, mysqli

I have a login page page called login.php with the following php code:

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    include ('databaseconnect.php');

 if(isset($_POST['login'])){
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

 $query = "select Username, Userid, user_type from Users
           where username = '$username'
           and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $username = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 if ($username ['user_type'] == 'owner') {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username['Username'];    
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid['Userid'];          
        $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type['user_type']; 
        header('location:adminmain.php');
}else{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username['Username'];       
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid['Userid'];             
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type['user_type'];    
    header('location:usermain.php');
      }
     }
    }
   }
  ?>
```

A person's 'Username', 'Userid' and 'user_type' is suppose to be in $_SESSION from the time they login. When a person logs in there is a page called create_topic.php with the following code:

```
    <?php
      include ('dataconnect.php');

      $sql1= "SELECT Categoryid, Categoryname, Categorydescription 
             FROM Categories"; 
      $result1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);

   if (!$result1)
      {
     echo "No Category Found, Contact the administrator" </p>; 
      }

   function getPosts()
   {
    $posts = array();
    $posts[0] = $_POST['topic_subject'];
    $posts[1] = $_POST['topic_category'];
    $posts[2] = $_SESSION['username']; var_dump($_SESSION);
    return $posts;
   } 

   if (isset($_POST['createtopicbutton'])) 
    {  

   $data = getPosts();

   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Topics(Topic_subject, Topic_category, Topic_by)          
              VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]', '$data[2]')";

   $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);

   if ($result2)
    {
       echo  "<p> Topic Successfully Created </p>";
  }else{
       echo "<p> Topic NOT! Successfully Created, Contact the administrator 
              </p>. mysqli_error($db); 
       } 
      }
    ?>
```

However when the above code is executed I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax  to use
>   near 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Topic_by'  at row 1
>   VALUES('t' at line 1.

So I did a var_dump I found this:

```
 array (size=3)
 'username' => string 'Owner1' (length=6)
 'userid' => null
 'user_type' => null.
```

So What I am specifically asking is how can the 'username' be stored but 'userid' and 'user_type' be null when it was stated at the login.php page. Your help and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your 1st page has session_start(); and your 2nd page doesn't. Both and ALL that use $_SESSION need to have session_start();

Comment: If you're using MySQLi please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as your query is vulnerable to MySQL injection. Plus it will likely correct the SQL error you are getting.

Comment: Please do not store passwords in plaintext in your database. Use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are incorrect, try:

```
 if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    $query = "select Username, Userid, user_type from Users
           where username = '$username'
           and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($user ['user_type'] == 'owner')
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['Username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['Userid'];
            $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user['user_type'];
            header('location:adminmain.php');
        } else
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['Username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['Userid'];
            $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user['user_type'];
            header('location:usermain.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Only `$username` is defined, `$userid` and `$user_type` are not, `user_type` and `userid` are indexes of `$username` not separate variables. So, instead use `$user`, so it will be more readable.

### Warning!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Hi, it works but why is it storing the 'userid' as a string and not  as an integer which is how it was defined in the database and becase of this when I try to enter data I am getting this error: 'Incorrect integer value: 'Owner1' for column 'Topic_by' at row 1'. Note Owner1 is the username not the userid.

Comment: @electricslide58 just use `(int)$user['Userid'];`